# Исправьте лексико-стилистические ошибки

Tags: стилистика

а) Отчёт сдайте в апреле месяце.
б) Золотая медаль была компенсацией за её трудолюбие, отчаяние, гордость.
в) Дружки Олега Кошевого создали подпольную организацию.
г) Передо мной стояла альтернатива: идти в кино или мыть пол.
д) Спортсмены потерпели победу в соревнованиях.
е) Ваши требования обоснованы на предположениях.

Comment: Мы тут домашние задания не делаем. Дайте ваш вариант – посмотрим.

ЗЫ Бог ты мой... Шестой класс максимум.

Comment: Это все один вариант. Я сделал так, но не уверен в правильности.
Отчет сдайте в апреле.
За ее трудолюбие отчаяние гордость была выдана золотая медаль.
Дружки олега кошевого создали подпольную организацию.
У меня была альтернатива: мыть пол или идти в кино.
Спортсмены одержали победу в соревнованиях.
Ваши требования основаны на предположениях

Comment: Компенсация может быть за что-то плохое. Трудолюбие и гордость – плохое?

Дружки – приятели, слово скорее с негативной окраской. Вы не знаете, кто такой Олег Кошевой?

Альтернатива – другая возможность. Не подходит.

Доделывайте.

Comment: >>Альтернатива – "другая возможность". Не подходит.  
  
Вот тут как раз большой вопрос. В современном языке есть как минимум равноправное значение: выбор из двух (или) более возможностей. И я совсем не уверен, какое из двух значений употребительнее и первичнее.

Answer (score 1):

Задумался...
Автор, конечно, намекал, что **стоит** вопрос, а альтернатива... 
*Да, что делает альтернатива?*

Не *лежит* же?
Остальное очевидно.

(+)
[[@Niemand](/users/3758/niemand)](/users/3758/niemand)

> > Альтернатива – "другая возможность". Не подходит.

Вот тут как раз большой вопрос. В современном языке есть как минимум равноправное значение: выбор из двух (или) более возможностей. И я совсем не уверен, какое из двух значений употребительнее и первичнее.

Большой толковый словарь (Кузнецов)
АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА [тэ], -ы; ж. [франц. alternative].
 1. Необходимость выбора между двумя или несколькими исключающими друг друга возможностями.
 2. Каждая из этих возможностей. Иметь альтернативу.

Первое значение вполне допускает понимание и "стоял выбор" и "стояла необходимость".

Comment: >> Автор, конечно, намекал, что стоит вопрос, а альтернатива...

Думаю, автор намекал, что стоит дилемма.

Comment: Вполне возможен вариант "возникла альтернатива"

Comment: Передо мной стоял выбор, у меня была альтернатива.